# Two-quadrant sinusoidal (3-phase) PWM generation

Tags: motor, pwm, three-phase

I have a true sinusoidal BLDC driver, PWM of which works in Bi-polar, Complementary mode. [image: See PWM modes]

I have to make it Uni-polar independent or Bi-polar independent, so the operation to become two-quadrant instead of four-quadrant as it is now.

And just can't understand how to do it in case of sinusoidal drive, where all three phases are permanently "on" with some values.

So it must be something like [image: this]

but for sinusoidal control and not 6-step like in this example.

Thanks.

Comment: True sinusoidal BLDC driver does not make sense... BLDC machines are optimised with a trapezoidal phase BACKEMF to facilitate a quazi square wave voltage as this is simpler from a control POV (sacrifices torque ripple and overall control). Can a BLDC machine be driven with. Sinus source? It's just a sync machine at the end of the day... Doesn't change the fact what you describe doesn't make sense

Comment: The back-EMF of myne BLDC is sinusoidal, so there is no mistake. Nevertheless it's still a brushless dc motor)

Comment: are you viewing it line-line or phase voltage. A BLDC will have a slightly triangular shape line-line and a trap phase voltage. DEPENDING on the quality of the emag design w.r.t. the motor, it may have been poorly designs specifically for BLDC or it may actually have been designed as a BLAC.. you say it is a BLDC motor yet you want to drive it with a sinus driver... it will work but you then say it is a BLDC motor but with a sinus backEMF... things are not aligning.

Comment: Ok, it's better to say it is a PMSM. Viewing line-line. It definitely has a sinusoidal back-EMF. BLDC is just a more understandable for everyone term.